# Room: query with subquery. How to model the dataclasses?

Tags: kotlin, subquery, android-room, data-class

I would like to perform a query on a room database that results in a list of records, which are composed of columns from several tables. First I have a subquery which is then joined with another table. In the result I select only a few columns. In this query I use 3 tables.

When I compile the project I get the error saying:

**Cannot figure out how to read this field from a cursor. private org.joda.time.DateTime createdDate;**.

The error points to this DateTime field.

Here is my interface:

```
@Dao
interface SomeObjectDao {
  @Query (
    SELECT a.Id, a.number, b.CreatedDate as createdDate
    FROM (SELECT p.*, q.*
          FROM tableP AS p, tableQ AS q
          WHERE p.userId = q.userId) AS a, table2 AS b
    WHERE a.Id = b.someId AND a.position = b.position)
  fun getSummary(): List<SomeObjectSummaryDB>
}
```

and my custom class for the SomeObjectSummaryDB looks like this:

```
class SomeObjectSummaryDB(
  var Id: String,
  var number: Int,

  @TypeConverters(DateTimeConverter::class)
  var createdDate: DateTime
)
```

I have seen some examples showing the use of the @Embedded and @ForeignKey annotations. Is this something I need in this case? If so, can anyone help me what is needed to get my list of objects?

Do I need to make a model for both the subquery and the overall result?
If so, how would these models look like?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem; the issue here is that I created the class with a constructor, but what I needed was a class with properties. Like this:

```
class SomeObjectSummaryDB {
  var id: String = ""
  var number: Int = 0
  @TypeConverters(DateTimeConverter::class)
  var createdDate: DateTime = DateTime()
}
```

Not that the @Entity annotation is not needed here.